# Error in referencing multi foreign-key attribute for same model in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use a sequelize model that referencing the same model using two foreign keys. I don't have problem in creating the parent model. But when I read them it gives error saying `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.`

Here is my model definitions and how I select it.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    //common fields
  }, {});
  Product.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Product.belongsTo(models.Unit, {
      as: 'stockUnit',
      foreignKey: 'stockUnitFk'
    })
    Product.belongsTo(models.Unit, {
      as: 'retailUnit',
      foreignKey: 'retailUnitFk'
    })
  };
  return Product;
};
```

--

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Unit = sequelize.define('Unit', {
    name: {type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true},
  }, {});
  Unit.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return Unit;
};
```

--

```
Product.findAll({inculde: [Unit]}).then(products => {
            products.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.stockUnit.name) //this gives an error
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Product.findAll({ include: [{ model: Unit, as: 'stockUnit' }] }).then(products => {

})
```

> If an association is aliased (using the `as` option), you must specify
>   this alias when including the model. Instead of passing the model
>   directly to the `include` option, you should instead provide an object
>   with two options: `model` and `as`

See https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#fetching-an-aliased-association